# How to integrate Twitter and Post tweet in application with common code using Phonegap for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, twitter, cordova

I want to Integrate twitter to Login and Post Tweet within the application How can I do that with Phonegap?
I have tried to search for Twitter Phonegap plugin but its deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do use of Twitter integration on PhoneGap. look this example [example](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms)  and use this steps.

Comment: Without using Child browser Please

Comment: use  InAppBrowser Bhavik

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind posting it via the native Twitter interface, check this out: http://www.x-services.nl/phonegap-share-plugin-facebook-twitter-social-media/754